# Find what day from UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, strtotime, unix-timestamp

I want to find out what day it is from a unix timestamp. For example `1322784000` should really tell me that this timestamp is the `First Friday`, where as  `1326989000` would return `Third Thursday`. I have no idea where to start, has anyone done anything like this before and can lend me a hand.

Comment: "the first Friday" - the first Friday since what?

Comment: First friday of what, the month?

Comment: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm, http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: `First` and `Third` weekday of the year or of the month??

Comment: start with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and try it here http://codepad.org/Sd9lhTLk

Comment: @Octopus-Paul: I did not know about codepad.org before. Thanks. It is a great site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to figure out that:

```
$ts=array(1322784000, 1326989000, 1323216000, strtotime('2011-12-28'), strtotime('2011-12-21'), strtotime('2011-12-28'), strtotime('2011-12-29') );
foreach ($ts as $t) {
   $dt = new DateTime('@' . $t);
   $d = ceil($dt->format('d')/7);
   $str="";
   switch ($d) {
      case 1: $str = "1st ";
         break;
      case 2: $str = "2nd ";
         break;
      case 3: $str = "3rd ";
         break;
      case 4: $str = "4th ";
         break;
      default: $str = "5th ";
         break;
   }
   echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " is: " . $str . $dt->format('l') . "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2011-12-02 00:00:00 is: 1st Friday
2012-01-19 16:03:20 is: 3rd Thursday
2011-12-07 00:00:00 is: 1st Wednesday
2011-12-28 00:00:00 is: 4th Wednesday
2011-12-21 00:00:00 is: 3rd Wednesday
2011-12-28 00:00:00 is: 4th Wednesday
2011-12-29 00:00:00 is: 5th Thursday
```

Comment: This has the same bug as Sarwar's. 1323216000 reports as the second Wednesday.

Comment: You're right, I should have used `ceil` function instead of `floor`. Updated my answer with lots of boundary test cases.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to pass all the test that Sarwar's failed on.

Answer (score -1):

This post can porobably help you: http://filchiprogrammer.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/getting-the-first-monday-of-the-month/#comment-594